# Join particles with parent surface

Tags: texturing, node-editor, particles

I am new to Blender and learning by making a donut with sprinkles on icing. Sprinkles are generated on icing with Particle, and colors are random thank to `ColorRamp` node.
Then I try to merge all sprinkles with incing. I `Convert` the Particle Modifier, then press `Ctrl+J` to join all selected parts.
Problem is that I loose all random colors after it.
How to join all this parts to one object, by keeping textures that have been randomly generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new "Random per Island" output from the "Geometry" node. This only works with **Cycles Renderer**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my attempts were unsuccessful. Do you apply these nodes on each sprinkle after Modifier is converted, or only on the template of sprinkle, before applying Modifier?

Comment: You want to set only this material to the sprinkles object after joining them all with `CTRL J`

Comment: Wow, thank you!